# eloipool fails with module 'select' has no attribute 'EPOLLIN'

Tags: mining-pools

attempting to run [eloipool](https://github.com/luke-jr/eloipool) by following the [tutorial in the issues section](https://github.com/luke-jr/eloipool/issues/3). When running eloipool.py, I am greeted with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eloipool.py", line 84, in <module>
    from bitcoin.node import BitcoinLink, BitcoinNode
  File "/Users/harshagoli/Projects/eloipool/bitcoin/node.py", line 22, in <module>
    import networkserver
  File "/Users/harshagoli/Projects/eloipool/networkserver.py", line 28, in <module>
    EPOLL_READ = select.EPOLLIN | select.EPOLLPRI | select.EPOLLERR | select.EPOLLHUP
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'EPOLLIN'
```

Running with python3, and in the python3 repl select does have the correct attributes, but in the script itself it doesn't seem to load.

Comment: Are you certain the python interpreter you're actually running is version 3?  The tutorial talks about just using the `python` command, but on many systems that will give you version 2, even if version 3 is also installed.  What is the full command line you are using, and what do you see if you run the same command with `--version`?

Comment: I am sure I'm using python3. I use `python3 eloipool.py` and get the error I posted above